# Почему не работает путь к файлу с обратным слешем?Система Windows.Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему возникает ошибка ТОЛЬКО во втором случае?Все работает когда
меняется слеш в пути к файлу на обратный:`text/book.txt (получается путь как у Linux)`

```
book = "text\spravka.txt"
with open(book) as word:
    words = word.read()

book = "text\book.txt"
with open(book) as word:
    words = word.read()
```

Comment: двойной слеш пробуй

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тк в \book со слешем получится [Спец. символ](http://www.tryobj.com/66-oprog-22.html)
\b  backspace

Comment: Спасибо!!!Теперь понятно

Answer (score 7):

Причина в экранировании символа при использовании `\`

Правильно пути складывать так (литеральные варианты):

- `book = "text\\spravka.txt"`
- `book = r"text\spravka.txt"`
- `book = "text/spravka.txt"`

Либо используя специальные функции, например `os.path.join`:

```
import os
book = os.path.join("text", "spravka.txt")
```

---

Если посмотреть во что экранируются символы, становится понятно, что что-то случилось неправильное (подробное объяснение этому дали [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/652931/201445)):

```
>>> '\book'
'\x08ook'
>>> '\spravka'
'\\spravka'
>>> '\programming'
'\\programming'
```

Comment: @andreymal, а что там за отпечатка такая странная была? Вроде бы, они одинаковые :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не разобрался в этом:почему "text\spravka.txt", "text\career.txt","text\programming.txt" работает и другие, а путь "text\book.txt" требует именно вариант обратного слеша, либо как вы написали.Чем не нравиться Python имя файла book?

Comment: @Александр, существует экранированная последовательность \b (он же служебный символ, принцип такой же как и у \r \n). С одним слешом он пытается применить её.  Для \s, \c, \p таких последовательностей нет, по этому обработчик и не ругался 

Более подробно можете прочитать здесь: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-literaly-strok.html

Comment: Дмитрий,спасибо!!Помогло убрать пробелы в знаниях.

Comment: Опечатка - кавычка забытая

Comment: @andreymal, ааааа, а я смотрю txt -> txt и думаю что не так было :D